# Validating that a property exists in either of two different objects

Tags: jsonschema

(Side-note: I'm limited to using json-schema draft 7, because I'm working to modify a SchemaStore schema)

I'm trying to build a JSON schema definition that's capable of validating that a property is set if a certain property exists in a *different* part of the document.  (The real-world situation is validating that the `shell` property is defined in a GitHub workflow, if the real-world application turns out to be relevant).

The structure of the document, in relevant part, looks like this:

```json
{
  "default": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "jobs": {
    "blargh": {
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "frob",
          "use": "frob",
        },
        {
          "name": "blingle",
          "run": "thingummy",
          "foo": "baz"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON schema needs to fail validation if neither of `/default/foo` or `/jobs/*/steps/*/foo` exists, in those elements of `/jobs/*/steps/*` which contain a `run` property.

Hence, the above example document should successfully validate.  It should also successfully validate if `/defaults/foo` is deleted, *or* if `/jobs/blargh/steps/1/foo` is deleted (because there is a `/defaults/foo` defined).  However, it should fail validation if *both* `/defaults/foo` *and* `/jobs/blargh/steps/1/foo` are deleted, because that is an invalid document.

I've gotten as far as something like this for the schema:

```json
{
  // In the definition of `/jobs/*/steps/*`
  "dependencies": {
    "foo-defined": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "foo": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
            }
        },
        {
           // THIS IS WHERE I FALL DOWN
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to say "this other thing aaaaaaaall the way over here must exist" in a JSON schema.  Am I missing something, or is this not expressible?

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you need to put the constraint at a high enough level in the schema so that you can use the usual keywords to whatever depth you need. In this case, you'll have to put your constraint at the root of the schema.

```json
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "default": { "required": ["foo"] }
      },
      "required": ["default"]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "jobs": {
          "patternProperties": {
            "": {
              "properties": {
                "steps": {
                  "contains": { "required": ["foo"] }
                }
              },
              "required": ["steps"]
            }
          },
          "minProperties": 1
        }
      },
      "required": ["jobs"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Ooof, that's gonna sting, if I'm understanding you correctly.  Since the jobs/steps part of the document are required regardless of whether the "foo" is default'd or not, does that mean I have to duplicate all that part of the schema on both arms of the "anyOf", and just change whether or not "foo" is required based on whether I'm on the "I have a default" subschema or not?

Comment: No, you don't need to duplicate anything. Write out your schema as you normally would, then add exactly what's in this answer to the end of your schema. This is adding a (complex) constraint to your already established schema.

Comment: Ooooooooh!  That sounds far more practical.  I shall give it a whirl.